# Add a value to a list everytime the user answers correctly

Tags: android, list

I have a code written where a user has to answer a question true or false. What I want to do is everytime when a user answers correctly I add +1 to my arraylist. And then at the end of the game I display the number of answered questions. I tried to do it my way, however I get an error.

Here is how I create my list:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This is the button if the user presses True(For better understanding: When a user presses true a pop up window opens with the answer correct or false and the correct answer of the question. When the user clicks on the closepopup button an if method runs and checks if he pressed the right button and if its not the last question. If not,  it shows the next question and adds the +1 to the list):

```
mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
                if(type.get(count[0])){

                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Correct!");
                } else {
                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("False!");
                }
               //Show the first answer on first button click.
                ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstas)).setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).answer);
        // When PopUp button closes open the next question with the if/else conditions.
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //if the question is true show next question/ else close app
                    if (type.get(count[0])) {
                        points.add(1); // if the answer is correct add +1 to the list.
                        if(questions.size()-1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
                        {

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("WInner");
                            builder.setMessage("You won, play again?");
                            builder.setCancelable(false);
                            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            // just close dialog
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                         finish();

                                            mResult.setText(points.size());// here I try to print the number of answered questions.

                                        }
                                    });

                            // Create dialog from builder
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                            // Show dialog
                            alert.show();
                            count[0]=0;


                        }
                        else if(questions.size()-1 < count[0])
                            try {
                                throw new Exception("Invalid ");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        else
                        count[0]++;

                        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                        pwindo.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        count[0]++;

                        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                        pwindo.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });

            }
        });
```

**EDITED!!!**

I figured out why SetText shows a blank textview. I want to show the answered question count in activity before the questions. I have a menuActivity>LevelselectActivity>GameActivity. In game activity I add to the list values. How to post them in LevelselectActivity? Should I use shared preferences? I have no idea now..

Comment: What's the error?  A crash?  Then post the stack trace.  A wrong result?  Then post what you actually got and what you expected.

Comment: Updated with the Logcat.

Comment: setText(""+questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size());

Comment: @Der Golem I tried creating an global array like: final int[] points = {0}; and ad points++ everytime. However It didn't work for some reason and I always got nullPointerException error.

Comment: if you are setting a variable into TextView that is not a string, cast it to String. like:setText(""+questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size());                                                                                         May be it help you

Comment: Hm. I wrote the code like this: mResult.setText(""+ points.get((count[0]) % points.size()));. It doesn't show me any errors, however It doesn't post he number aswell, I get a blank textview. Maybe I am adding values the wrong way and the list is empty?

Comment: The purpose of the list is to keep track of how many questions were answered, and how many answered correctly?  Would it be simpler to just have two counters?